# When are the props `propName` and `componentName` passed to the `PropTypes` functions?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

**Background**

1. The `Message` function is created

   - `const Message = ({text}) => <p>{text}</p>`
2. It's given a `propTypes` property

   - `Message.propTypes = { text: PropTypes.string }`
3. `PropTypes` is defined as

```js
const PropTypes = {
  string(props, propName, componentName) {
    debugger;  // intentional
    if (typeof props[propName] !== 'string') {
      return new Error('')
    }
  },
}
```

**Question**

Where on earth are `propName` and `componentName` defined?

**What I've tried**

I can get a breakpoint in `PropTypes.string` to pause when I call `React.createElement(Message)`

I can't get to the breakpoint when I just call the function itself `Message({text: "123"})` so I know that these props are defined in `React.createElement`

So I looked at the `React.createElement` definition but I'm a bit stumped after looking at the function

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/cae635054e17a6f107a39d328649137b83f25972/packages/react/src/ReactElement.js#L349

**How I got to this question**

I've been going through the Epic React course and I'm at part 4 of React Fundamentals

https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-fundamentals/blob/main/src/final/04.extra-3.html

Answer (score 0):

> Where on earth are propName and componentName defined?

Those are parameters that get passed in to your function by the prop-types library. propName is the name of the prop that's being tested (`"text"` in this case) and componentName is the name of the component (`"Message"` in this case);

[Here's the line in prop-types which calls your function](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/blob/main/checkPropTypes.js#L62)

You can control what value is used for componentName by adding a displayName property to your component, as in:

```
const Message = ({text}) => <p>{text}</p>
Message.displayName = "Aardvark";
```

If no `.displayName` is provided, then the function's `.name` property is used instead (assuming the function isn't anonymous)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

I tried to simplify my scenario by not use the `prop-types` library and instead using a simplified `PropTypes.string` so I'm still not sure where `propName` and `componentName` are. I have a feeling that I have a link to the wrong `React.createElement` in my question because I'm stumped after reading that function